# LWP Send Post request and get headers only in response

Tags: perl, lwp

I have code like this

```
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
$ua->timeout($timeout);
$ua->agent($useragent);
$response = $ua->post($domain,['login_name'=>$login,'login_password'=> $password])->as_string;
```

Content of page so large, thatI can't receive it. How to get only headers with sending post data?

Comment: How is it that the response it so big that you can't receive it?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it for you.

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->timeout($timeout);
$ua->agent($useragent);
my $response = $ua->post( 
    $domain,
    [ 'login_name' => $login, 'login_password' => $password ] 
);

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper( $response->headers() );
print $response->request()->content(), "\n";
```

Comment: This answer does not answer the question. What are the error mesaages?

Answer (score 1):

To first, check if you can pass this `login_name` and `login_password` via HEAD (in url string: `domain/?login_name=...&login_password=...`). If this will not work, you are in bad case.

You cannot use POST with behavior of HEAD. LWP will wait full response.

Using POST the server will send you the content anyway, but you can avoid receiving all content using sockets tcp by yourself: **gethostbyname**, **connect**, **sysread** until you get `/\r?\n\r?\n/` and close socket after this. Some traffic will be utilized anyway, but you can save memory and receive time.

Its not normal thing to do this with sockets, but sometimes when you have highload/big data - there is no better way than such mess.